# purpose of second 'spec'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am a bit confused on this kubernetes yaml file. The first 'spec' says there need to be 3 replicas all the time.

How about the second 'spec' that just above 'containers'. Also, what does the template thing do ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: node-js
  labels:
    name: node-js
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
   name: node-js
 template:
metadata:
 labels:
 name: node-js
 spec:
 containers:
 - name: node-js
   image: jonbaier/node-express-info:latest
   ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

The first spec is for settings of the [ReplicationController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/#writing-a-replicationcontroller-spec) itself.

Block named "template" and "spec" in it is a [pod template](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#pod-templates) with a configuration of the pod which you want to run by your replication controller:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: node-js
  labels:
    name: node-js
spec: # related to ReplicationController itself
 replicas: 3 # value 3 mean that you want to launch 3 replicas of a pod
 selector:
   name: node-js
 template: # section with a pod template
   metadata:
     labels:
       name: node-js
   spec: # related to a container you want to run
     containers:
     - name: node-js
       image: jonbaier/node-express-info:latest
       ports:
        - containerPort: 80`